# Solve $\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}{\frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2-1}}\int_{0}^{x}{{\left(\arctan{t}\right)}^{2}\mathrm{d}t}}$

Tags: limits, definite-integrals, trigonometric-integrals

I have to solve the following limit: $\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}{\frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2-1}}\int_{0}^{x}{{\left(\arctan{t}\right)}^{2}\mathrm{d}t}}$. The problem for me is the definite integral. I tried $t=\tan{p}$ from where I get $\int_{0}^{x}{{p^{2}\mathrm{d}\tan{p}}}$ and then I integrated by parts but that didn't work. I also considered somehow inserting $\frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2-1}}$ inside the integral but I think that would complicate things even more. How can I solve the limit?

Comment: It is of the form $\infty/\infty$. You may apply Hopital's rule.

Comment: How can I apply L'Hospital for a definite integral? An example will be of great help.

Comment: Apply the fundamental theorem of calculus: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_calculus#First_part 
 See egreg's answer below.

Comment: A very similar question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3602326/evaluate-lim-limits-x-to-infty-frac-int-0x-left-arctan-t-right2-dt?rq=1

Comment: You may replace $\sqrt{x^2-1}$ by $|x|$ before applying L'Hospital's Rule.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not need to compute the integral. By applying de l'Hôpital's rule you find
\begin{align*}
\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2-1}}\int_0^x (\arctan t)^2dt & = \lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{\arctan^2 x}{x(x^2-1)^{-1/2}} \\
& = \lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{|x|\left(1-\frac{1}{x^2}\right)^{1/2}}{x} \arctan^2 x \\
& = \pm \frac{\pi^2}{4}
\end{align*}
and the sign depends on wether you are taking the limit for $x \to \pm \infty$.

Answer (score 3):

You can apply l'Hôpital to any form $?/\infty$, where the question mark means any function that's differentiable where needed. On the other hand, it's not difficult to show that
$$
\lim_{x\to\infty}\int_0^x(\arctan t)^2\,dt=\infty
$$
so you can apply the standard form.

The fundamental theorem of calculus then allows you to compute
$$
\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{(\arctan x)^2}{x/\sqrt{x^2-1}}
$$
and this is not indeterminate.